# EC2 ubuntu : unable to access site from browser but able to access from EC2 ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, dns

Below is my virtual host setup

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin ******.com
        ServerName ***.***.com
        ServerAlias www.***.***.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/***.***.com/public_html
        <Directory /var/www/***.***.com >
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Required all granted
        </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>
```

When I do curl `http://***.***.com/` from  ec2 ubuntu terminal,it is printing the *hello world html*. Working nicely.

Now When I access `http://***.***.com/` from browser ,its says `This site can’t be reached`

**NOTE :**

I have enabled my `***.***.com.conf`.

permission also given.

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /var/www/***.***.com/public_html
```

I have enabled the port 80 to listen on `0.0.0.0`

**netstat -nlp output**

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -               
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -               
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           -
```

Will you please help me what I am missing.

Comment: Did you open port 80  on your firewall?

Comment: @mikep yes I have opened it.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following to ensure that its working.

**Assumptions**

- Your EC2 instance is provisioned inside a Public Subnet
- Your EC2 instance is having a valid Public IP/Public DNS/Elastic IP
- Your domain is configured to point to the Public IP/Elastic IP/Public DNS of your EC2 instance

**Domain Redirection to the EC2 Instance**

- Ping `ping ***.***.com` and check domain is properly pointing to the public IP of your EC2 instance (Assuming you dont have any ELBs or other entities in between)

**Check EC2 Security Group Configuration**

- Check the security group of your EC2 and ensure that you have a rule which is allowing incoming access to port 80 from source 0.0.0.0/0

**Check ACL Rules of your VPC**

- Ensure that the ACL rules in the VPC where your EC2 is provisioned is not blocking incoming access to port 80. (Default ACL rules if not modified should be working)

**If all the above are checked, still not working**

- Modify the Virtual Host part slightly like below and try

`<VirtualHost <your_ec2_private_ip_here>:80>`